# Export Value of Array of Object to Array of Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects like

```
var dataSet1 = {
    1: {
        AnnualFirmEnergy: "91.2335550",
        CostOfEnergy: "183.835765",
        CostPerYear: "16771990.38",
        Footprint: "182.3077770",
        InstalledCapacity: "31.320802",
        Penstock: "5000.000000"
    },
    2: {
        AnnualFirmEnergy: "91.2335550",
        CostOfEnergy: "183.835765",
        CostPerYear: "16771990.38",
        Footprint: "182.3077770",
        InstalledCapacity: "31.320802",
        Penstock: "5000.000000"
    },
    3: {
        AnnualFirmEnergy: "91.2335550",
        CostOfEnergy: "183.835765",
        CostPerYear: "16771990.38",
        Footprint: "182.3077770",
        InstalledCapacity: "31.320802",
        Penstock: "5000.000000"
    }
}
```

Can you please let me know how I can convert/parse it's `Values` into Array of Array like

```
var dataSet1 = [
   [ "91.2335550", "183.835765", "1677190.38", "182.3077770", "31.320802","50"],
   [ "91.2335550", "183.835765", "1677190.38", "182.3077770", "31.320802","50"],
   [ "91.2335550", "183.835765", "1677190.38", "182.3077770", "31.320802","50"],
   ....
];
```

Comment: Your first example is actually an object of objects. You should look into `Object.keys` function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: are you sure `dataSet1` is an array?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cmkj6jac/

Comment: Hi Arun, thanks for the fiddle but wht do you mean by `are you sure dataSet1 is an array?`

Comment: Your starting data is not an array.

Comment: Are you taking about First (Object) one? or you mean the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)** and **[`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)** in jQuery

```js
var dataSet1 = {
  1: {
    AnnualFirmEnergy: "91.2335550",
    CostOfEnergy: "183.835765",
    CostPerYear: "16771990.38",
    Footprint: "182.3077770",
    InstalledCapacity: "31.320802",
    Penstock: "5000.000000"
  },
  2: {
    AnnualFirmEnergy: "91.2335550",
    CostOfEnergy: "183.835765",
    CostPerYear: "16771990.38",
    Footprint: "182.3077770",
    InstalledCapacity: "31.320802",
    Penstock: "5000.000000"
  },
  3: {
    AnnualFirmEnergy: "91.2335550",
    CostOfEnergy: "183.835765",
    CostPerYear: "16771990.38",
    Footprint: "182.3077770",
    InstalledCapacity: "31.320802",
    Penstock: "5000.000000"
  }
};

var arr = [];
$.each(dataSet1, function(i,v) {
  arr.push($.map(v, function(v1) {
    return v1;
  }));
});

document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(arr,null,3)+'</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with jQuery, but I'll provide a native JavaScript way:

`dataSet1` is an object, not an array. It looks like an array because of the numbered values `1`, `2`, `3`, but it has the object curly braces `{ }`.

You can access each property of an object using `Object.keys`, and mapping the object values to an array will be your first step:

```
var arrayOfObjects = Object.keys(dataSet1).map(function (key) {
  return dataSet1[key]
})
```

This may be a useful result for you because you maintain the key values, but to get your answer you can simply `map` and `keys+map` again.

```
var arrayOfArrays = arrayOfObjects.map(function (obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
    return obj[key]
  })
})
```

Modern browsers have arrow functions now so the whole thing can be written as:

```
var arrayOfArrays = 
  Object.keys(dataSet1).map(key => dataSet1[key])
    .map(obj => Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]))
```